# Mount Samsung S10 file system to Windows 10

Tags: samsung, factory-reset, file-system, mtp

Is it not possible to mount and browse the file system with Samsung Galaxy S10 if I connect it to Windows 10? With Galaxy S8 it was possible and I could easily traverse the file system of the phone to make sure that I did and did not have files in the phone before I erased and reset it. Now I want to erase and reset my S10 but I find no good way of checking its file system the way that I did with the S8.

Comment: All that you can access is shared external storage i.e. `/sdcard`. That's always accessible over MTP or ADB. Are you talking about something else? How exactly was that possible with S8?

Comment: @IrfanLatif With S8 then I just connected it with a USB cable between the laptop and the phone and the phone appeared as a device and I could browse the file system. With S10 and Windows 10 that does not work, but I have the phone app from Microsoft which I can use to control my phone. And when I connect the S10 to Ubuntu then I can browse the file system of the S10 the way I want so using Ubuntu is my workaround for now.

Comment: So your MTP is not working with S10 and Windows 10 but works with Ubuntu. Do you see/hear any notification on Windows when you plug/unplug your phone to Windows? Some changes in Device Manager? Also check [MTP](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtp) tag.